# Set button constraints properly to show at the bottom of the screen in objective C programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I was trying to show a button on the bottom of the screen it was coming above safe area and it was not expected.

**Expected position:** How to show exactly as like in below image.

[image]

**Current implementaion:** With my current implementation it was showing above safeAreaLayoutGuide and it was not expected. button height can be 50 px left 20 px and right 20 px.

[image]

Here is the code tried by me.

```objectivec
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self
           action:@selector(buttonTapped:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Go back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:button];
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
```

Setting constraints programmatically in Objective C.

```objectivec
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [button.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor constant:20],
    [button.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor constant:-20],
    [button.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor constant:0]
]];
```

How to set constraints properly to show button as shown in first image.

Comment: So is that view you're adding it to the one with that light gray border? If so, the constraints are doing what you told it to do, namely align the _bottom_ of the button with the bottom of the view. Your top example looks like the _top_ of the button is aligned (with a little space) to the bottom of the view with the light gray border.

Comment: This is a little unclear as it's not at all clear what your view hierarchy is (where that gray line/border is coming from, to what `self.view` refers, etc.). I'd suggest either showing us the view hierarchy for your design, or somehow annotating the image a bit.

Comment: yes I need to debug some other view(close to Gray color view) is getting displayed behind Go to Search or below Go back button. When I check in view hierarchy it was shows the another view which is not part of this view controller I need to debug in order to find why this view is getting displayed here.

Answer (score -2):

The user is asking how to set button constraints properly to show at the bottom of the screen in Objective C programmatically. Here is an example code that you can use to set constraints programmatically in Objective C:

```objectivec
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitle:@"Go back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
[self.view addSubview:button];
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [button.leftAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor constant:20],
    [button.rightAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.rightAnchor constant:-20],
    [button.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor constant:0]
]];
```

This code sets the constraints for a button to be at the bottom of the screen. You can adjust the height, left and right margins of the button by changing the values in the constraints.

Comment: ChatGPT generated content.